# Error code 1004 (Application-defined or Object-defined error) with range and advanced filter

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone,
I'm trying to use an advanced filter per macro. The filter itself works perfectly fine when using without a macro.
Since I added a Range which is dependent on a variable, the range does not work anymore and just responed with error code 1004 (Application-defined or Object-defined error).

```
sub DataFilter()

Dim lastrowLTCSREP As Long
lastrowLTCSREP = Sheets("LTCS REP").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("LTCS REP").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrowLTCSREP, 3)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("tbl_filtercriteria"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("Repair").Range("A2:C2"), _
    Unique:=False

end sub
```

So the filter is supposed to get the data specified in "tbl_filtercriteria" and paste it in the specified range. The extract range, however, is the only range dependent on a range which is not fixed, but calculated.

By now, the above named error occurs all the time.

Does anyone know, how I can handle this?
I already googled a lot and also found a query on this website but all the stuff mentioned in there didn't really help me solving this.

Comment: ***ALL*** Range Object, which includes `Cells()` need to have the parent sheet assigned.  `Worksheets("LTCS REP").Range(Worksheets("LTCS REP").Cells(2, 1), Worksheets("LTCS REP").Cells(...`

Comment: in support of @ScottCraner's comment and ease of coding, using a `With` block in this instance will help a lot :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! That really helped me out.